# Temporal signal analysis in Weka

Tags: signals, weka, temporal

I am new in Weka. I am going to do an academic project in which I should take some signals coming from sensors, such that they are temporal data (I have a dataset with the readings of the sensor one distant from the other 5 seconds). So, I should take some instances of the readings which are labeled as correct and some other ones which are labeles as wrong, because the data has been perturbed. So, we are talking about supervised learning. This training step must be followed by a testing step to see if the system is able to detect some points in the signal which corresponds to a perturbed reading.
Anyway, I don't see in Weka a way to work with temporal data.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert your data into .arff format. Create some attributes based on your readings and label them with a class; in this case 'correct' or 'incorrect'. See here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Comment: I already converted my data in .arff format. My question was about the kind of algorithms (or more specifically, the more suitable algorithms) that I should use. For example, one of the datas is referring to a pression measurer and if I plot the graph I can see at a roughly glance a value on which most part of the readings are thickened. Sometimes there is a continuous group of point thickened on an higher level of value. And that's okay. But if I have an outline point, it is a pontential anomaly to detect by way of the algorithm.